# Installing PyUblas on Windows

Tags: python, c++, windows, visual-studio, installation

I'm trying to install PyUblas on my Windows machine. I have Visual Studio 2017 Community edition. I've tried installing using

```
pip install pyublas
```

but get the following error message:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ipyublas/include "-Ic:\users\my name\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" "-Ic:\users\my name\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" "-Ic:\users\my name\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" "-Ic:\users\my name\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include" "-Ic:\users\my name\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpsrc/wrapper/main.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\src/wrapper/main.obj -Wno-sign-compare
    cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-sign-compare'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.12.25827\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
    Command ""c:\users\my name\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\MYNAME~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-z0yc_qan\\PyUblas\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\MYNAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-2hhk4m35-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MYNAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-z0yc_qan\PyUblas\
```

On the [documentation](https://documen.tician.de/pyublas/installing.html#alternate-installation-using-boost-build) page there is also a two-line description of an alternative installation method using Boost.Build; however, it seems rather outdated or at least I wasn't able to get it to work or even to understand it. I've compiled Boost but not sure what I'm supposed to do then. It seems bjam has since been superceded by b2 but running that didn't help. I also couldn't find anything useful by searching either Google or on here.

EDIT:

I have tried removing the offending lines from setup.py and installing manually as per TheGreatParker's suggestion. I have also removed references to the flag in question in lines 109 and 119 because they were throwing up errors. Now I get the following error:

```
src/wrapper/main.cpp(16): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 
'boost/python.hpp': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.12.25827\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.12.25827\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I've tried copying the boost folder containing python.hpp into the installation folder but this didn't seem to help.

EDIT2:

I have rebuilt `boost` and made sure that the installation configuration file created by `configure.py` (which is `siteconf.py`) correctly links to the  `boost` directories. Now I get the following error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'boost_python36-vc141-mt-x32-1_67.lib'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.12.25827\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
```

I gather that the file it wants is in the boost library directory which for me is `boost_1_67_0\stage\lib\`. The file in question is actually called `libboost_python36-vc141-mt-x32-1_67.lib` so I thought the problem was that it was missing the 'lib' in the beginning. However, when I changed `siteconf.py`:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_LIBNAME = ['libboost_python36-vc141-mt-x32-1_67']
```

I got the following error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_pythonPY_MAJOR_VERSIONPY_MINOR_VERSION-vc141-mt-x32-1_67.lib'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.12.25827\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1104
```

Seems that either way it can't access this file. I have also tried making a copy of the file `libboost_python36-vc141-mt-x32-1_67` and renaming it what the installation is looking for. In this case I get a whole bunch of errors of the sort:

```
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) struct boost::python::converter::registration const * __cdecl boost::python::converter::registry::query(struct boost::python::type_info)" (__imp_?query@registry@converter@python@boost@@YAPBUregistration@234@Utype_info@34@@Z)
```

until the installation exits with error

```
build\lib.win32-3.6\pyublas\_internal.cp36-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 22 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.12.25827\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

Comment: Python3 can be used as embedded library in VS 2017. It can be installed rather easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install this package manually:

1. Clone source code;
2. Open `setup.py` and remove python logic which adds this flag. (in my version they are lines 16, and 17:

   ```
    StringListOption("CXXFLAGS", ["-Wno-sign-compare"],
       help="Any extra C++ compiler options to include"),
   ```
3. Use `python setup.py install` to install the package with changed `setup.py`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I've trying doings this but am now getting a different error having to do with a missing file. I've added a more detailed description to the original post.

Comment: try `pip install boost`, before installing from `setup.py`

Comment: I have rebuilt `boost` and made sure it is linked to correctly. Now I am getting a new error about `link.exe` not being able to open a file. I've appended a detailed account to the original question.

Comment: Do you install it with configure? `./configure.py` than `make` and than `sudo make install`  or via `python setup.py build`?  First case should configure the package correctly for you system.

Comment: I had run `configure.py` and then python install or build. I get the first error described under EDIT2 in OP. I'm on Windows so sudo/make doesn't work.

Comment: From the errors in EDIT2, it seems than linker doesn't see you boost libraries. Make sure that the enviroment vars `LIBPATH` and `LIB` have correct values. Because when you copied  `libboost_python36-vc141-mt-x32-1_67` to your local dir, It linked, but could not find the definitions of some functions.

Comment: To be clear I never copied `libboost_python36-vc141-mt-x32-1_67` to my local directory, I just made a copy where it is and renamed it `boost_python36-vc141-mt-x32-1_67` since that's what the installer complained it could't find. And that's when I got the new error about unresolved externals. So it does see into that directory. I'm not sure what LIBPATH and LIB are or how to change them. I have added `boost` root and lib directories to the Windows PATH variable but that didn't help.

I'm giving you the bounty for effort since it's about to expire anyway :).

Answer (score -1):

```
conda install pyublas
```

You need to install anaconda/miniconda from
https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html

Comment: This gave me the following error:

Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pyublas